# Running a passed proc with params inside a class instance in ruby

Tags: ruby, proc

This example is a bit contrived but it's from a test so it sort of just works this way and will help me figure out how to use this in the actual library. I have a lambda, defined like this:

```
l = lambda { |v| process(v) }
```

I want to pass this to an object and have the proc run in the context of that object. The object might look like this:

```
class LambdaRunner
  def process(v)
    puts v
  end
  def run(proc)
    # code to run proc in the context of the object
  end
end
```

I am familiar with the solution of running the proc using instance_eval.

```
instance_eval(&proc)
```

But this won't work because I need to pass a value to the proc. I've managed something like a working solution, but it feels hacky and error prone.

```
self.class.class_eval do
  define_method(:runner, &proc)
end
runner('hi from lambda runner')
```

All other method have been met with `undefined method process`

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation for [instance_exec](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_exec) (this is backported to 1.8.7). Assuming your proc takes a single argument `|v|`, you will probably end up with something like this in `LambdaRunner`.

```
  def run(proc)
    instance_exec(v_value, &proc)
  end
```

By the way, in version of Ruby that don't have `#instance_exec`, your hack is basically the only way to implement it. This was how I [**implemented it**](https://github.com/kputnam/stupidedi/blob/master/lib/ruby/instance_exec.rb) for older Rubies which didn't have the backported method.